# IOS Cocoa error 3840

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking to communicate with a database on my local server. Whenever I click register or login I receive and Error stating "The operation couldn't e completed. (Cocoa error 3840). I checked xcode and no error is being given back. Any help please

Comment: @H2CO3 Did that already couldn't find anything that worked!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I imagine that error is pretty spot on with what's happening, it sounds like the data being returned by your server is somehow mangled. It's also possible that the returned data is not valid.

As you can see from the Error's domain, it's a cocoa error. You can find the list of error's [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html) and the one you're experiencing, 3840, is most likely a `NSPropertyListReadCorruptError` error.

I would check on the data you're returning to figure out what's going on.